# what's the role of indefinite article in this phrase : he went into a rage!

Tags: indefinite-article

what the role of indefinite article in this phrase :

> He went into a rage!

The indefinite article doesn't make sense here what if we eliminate it from the sentence?

*edit:*
it doesn't make sense to me because rage for me is a mental state and  "a" for me is equal to one.. "one rage" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain why the indefinite article does not make sense?

Comment: @Andrew just did it! tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rage)'s first two definitions for "rage" are:

> **1a** "violent and uncontrolled anger" (meaning the emotion in general)

and

> **1b** "a fit of violent wrath" (a "fit" being a behavior caused by an instance of that emotion, an *episode* of angry behavior)

If you mean to use "rage" using its second definition (telling about the person's behavior, that he had an anger-tantrum, or a "**fit**" of violent anger), you would use the article and say, "He went into **a** rage."

The sentence without the article,"He went into rage.", would not be as common. Grammatically, it is OK, but it doesn't sound 100% idiomatic, mainly because there is a common expression, "to fly into **a** rage." So if you say "He *went* into *rage*." it sounds like a mis-statement of that expression, and we tend to hear it as a language error.

You could however discuss his emotional rage (1st definiton, no article) by saying something like,

> His emotion turned into rage.
>
> His mood became one of rage.
>
> He began to experience rage.
>
> He went from calm happiness to rage in an instant.